# Emscripten application not executing

Tags: c++, emscripten, asm.js

When running my asmjs\emscripten application, compiled from C++, it has suddenly started to log: `"run() called, but dependencies remain, so not running"` to the web console, and nothing more happens.
I've added some *cout's* at the absolute start of my main, but even they aren't reached.

The application executed successfully before, but suddenly this started to happen and I don't know what change triggered this.

Does anyone know how to debug this?

*Update*

After removing as much source code as I could, this happens as soon as I #include , even due my main simply consists of a single cout.

Answer (score 6):

Ideally you would have the entire environment when it was running in version control, and build every version since to see where it broke.

You might have your code in version control, but perhaps not Emscripten itself. If you've updated Emscripten, this could lead to differences in behaviour. I would try going back to whatever version you used when it was running. Note that sometimes various cache directories survive an Emscripten version change, and might need to be cleared manually (I forgot which exactly).

The dependencies remaining could mean that you are trying to do something before Emscripten has loaded any other files it needs to, say files requested by `--preload-file` or `--memory-init-file`. Note that according to https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#faq-when-safe-to-call-compiled-functions you should not try to run any Emscripten functions, until the C++ `main` function has run. To detect this, you can, for example, call your own Javascript function from `main` (there are other ways).

The fact this wasn't causing a problem before could have been something that seems quite unrelated: a change or update in the web browser, changing limits of concurrent downloads, or a change in the web server this is running from. You could look in the Network tab in the browser to see if anything leaps out at you as being different or suspicious.

However, as main isn't even reached, then it might not be that. I would try commenting out virtually all of your code, and make it so you have practically nothing but a hello-world program. Perhaps you don't have a correct setting in the Module object, or maybe the request for the memory initialization file is failing (you can check in the Network tab in the browser for that one). If your basic hello world program still isn't working, then you could post again, with its code, in a separate question.

Comment: I did as you said and as it seems, simply including sdl.h from a nearly empty project is enough to cause this.

Comment: @ViktorSehr I would post the details as a separate question, with the code + command line you're using to compile. (Your original question is "how I do I find what the issue is", but now it's "how do I fix this issue")

Comment: "simply including sdl.h from a nearly empty project is enough to cause this" I think you should go to the em_sdk tool and update your emscripten compiler to latest master branch, and also use the "clear cache" feature to make sure that it rebuilds its cached version of SDL from source. if you indeed have a problem with the (emscripten provided) SDL package, that is a bug you can report to alon I think

Comment: @ChrisBeck I'll do that

Answer (score 3):

This can also happens when the browser runs out of memory. Unfortunately, the browser's memory handling is not in our control so there isn't much you can do beside reducing your payload. This includes code size, preload content size, etc. Basically anything that can reduce the total memory consumption of your program will help fixing this. Browser vendors are constantly working to improve this, but it's going to take a while still.

Comment: I recommend editing "this happens when" --> "this can also happen when". Because for me this happened not because of the memory, but for the reason mentioned in Michal Charemza's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't given enough information to really know for sure. But it might be for instance that your js suddenly crossed some memory threshold which exceeds what the browser wants to allocate to it. You could try reducing the amount of memory used / streaming some assets instead of preloading them / ship less code / use -Os optimization level?